# Debugging Django with Werkzeug under WSGI/Passenger - problems

Tags: django, debugging, passenger, mod-wsgi, werkzeug

I'm trying to use the werkzeug debugger, but despite installing it as recommended, I just get the normal django error page.

from my passenger_wsgi.py:

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
application = DebuggedApplication(application, evalex=True)
```

**I'm largely constrained to running my django app (even in development) through passenger, not manage.py.**

Is there any way I can get the werkzeug debugger to work under these conditions? Could I, for instance prevent Django from intercepting the errors itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable Django exception handling with DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS setting. Then Werkzeug will be able to handle it.

Comment: I wonder both how you knew of this and how `runserver_plus` does this as it doesn't call `DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS`.

Comment: It was long time ago, but as I reconstruct this now, it seems that I've googled how to disable Django's internal exception handling. And I guess `runserver_plus` also somehow disable Django's middleware that handles exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy with the [django-command-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions). The [runserver_plus](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/runserver_plus.html) command features werkzeug debugger.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use manage.py. I have to run my app through passenger.

Comment: Can I not assume you need debugging only in your development environment where you are not tied to passenger?

Comment: No, for various reasons I develop in a hosted environment which constrains me to use passenger.

Comment: By the way, you are not intending to use werkzeug debugger on your production system, right? It allows code execution..

Answer (score 1):

This is because Django is intercepting any errors and converting them to an error page long before django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler() returns anything. You will not be able to get it working that way as application errors within your Django site will never propagate all the way back up to the top level.

Comment: OK, so is there any way to get the two to work together, or am I out of luck?

Comment: You can, just not the way you are doing it. A bit of Googling yields 'http://voices.canonical.com/isd/?p=116'. Am sure there is other information out there as well if you look.

Comment: Thanks - I assume you don't have any experience with that approach that you would care to share?